# check if two values in text box are the same

Tags: c#, database, textbox

I'm trying to check if two values are the same. For example the password and confirm password have to be the same. I have to check these and then to enter data in database. If the values are not same the data will not be entered.
How can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private bool Validate(String pass, String Confirm)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(pass) == false && pass == Confirm;
        }
```

Usage :

```
 if (Validate(TextBoxPass.Text, TextBoxConfirm.Text) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Passwords Do not Match");
                // Do Something;
            }
            else
            {
                // Submit Data to Database;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a very basic question... Consider reading some C# manual if you are not able to do that... anyway, this should work:

```
if (txtPassword.Text == txtRepeatPassword.Text)
{
    // Write what you want to DB here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx) to compare string. Here `Equals` and `Compare` functions have been demonstrated.

Hope it helps!